# How to pair the two arrays in bicep script?

Tags: arrays, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-bicep

Need to merge two arrays queuesName and serviceBusQueueNames. Need to reduce two resource into one by merging two arrays using bicep module. Compaining these arrays and need to get it into one resoure.

```
param queuesName array = []

var fullQueueNames = [for queueName in queuesName: '${env}-${queueName}' ]

resource serviceBusQueue 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues@2021-11-01' = [for queueName in fullQueueNames : {
  parent: serviceBusNamespace
  name: queueName
  properties: {
    lockDuration: 'PT5M'
    maxSizeInMegabytes: 1024
    requiresDuplicateDetection: false
    requiresSession: false
    defaultMessageTimeToLive: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
    deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration: false
    duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow: 'PT10M'
    maxDeliveryCount: 10
    autoDeleteOnIdle: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
    enablePartitioning: false
    enableExpress: false
  }
}]
```

Next array:

```
param serviceBusQueueNames array = []

var fullQueueNameslist = [for queueName in serviceBusQueueNames: '${queueName}-${environment}' ]

resource serviceBusQueues 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues@2022-01-01-preview' = [for queueName in fullQueueNameslist: {
  parent: serviceBusNamespace
  name: queueName
  properties: {
    lockDuration: 'PT5M'
    maxSizeInMegabytes: 1024
    requiresDuplicateDetection: false
    requiresSession: false
    defaultMessageTimeToLive: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
    deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration: false
    duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow: 'PT10M'
    maxDeliveryCount: 10
    autoDeleteOnIdle: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
    enablePartitioning: false
    enableExpress: false
  }
}]
```

Comment: i think `concat()` works as well

Comment: please add a **language** tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the union function...

```
param queuesName array = []
param serviceBusQueueNames array = []

var fullQueueNames = [for queueName in queuesName: '${env}-${queueName}']
var fullQueueNameslist = [for queueName in serviceBusQueueNames: '${queueName}-${environment}']

var mergedQueueNames = union(fullQueueNames, fullQueueNameslist)

resource serviceBusQueues 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/queues@2022-01-01-preview' = [
  for queueName in mergedQueueNames: {
    parent: serviceBusNamespace
    name: queueName
    properties: {
      lockDuration: 'PT5M'
      maxSizeInMegabytes: 1024
      requiresDuplicateDetection: false
      requiresSession: false
      defaultMessageTimeToLive: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
      deadLetteringOnMessageExpiration: false
      duplicateDetectionHistoryTimeWindow: 'PT10M'
      maxDeliveryCount: 10
      autoDeleteOnIdle: 'P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S'
      enablePartitioning: false
      enableExpress: false
    }
  }
]
```